# Joomla Mosets Tree Listings

Tags: php, joomla, directory, joomla-extensions

I have question about Joomla MOSETS TREE.

Is it possible to allow all registred users to modify (ALL) listings in directory?
Because, now they can modify only their own listings.

Answer (score 0):

I have an older MTree version and I've asked the developer (Lee) for the same thing and he told me MTree did not take advantage of all ACL features in Joomla, therefore it was not possible to grant edit privileges to other users.